# Updating a table in PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have the following, the trailing space after Price is on purpose:

```
UPDATE table1
SET "Price " = table2."Price"
FROM table2
WHERE table2."ATT2" = table1."ATT2"
```

This successfully returns:

> UPDATE 14

However, when i execute

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

table1 has not been updated with table2 prices as it should.

Complete code:

```
UPDATE table1
SET "Price " = table2."Price"
FROM table2
WHERE table2."ATT2" = table1."ATT2";
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Using pgAdmin4, tried this in psql client aswell but no luck. I'd rather use pdAdmin4.

This is not resolved so any help would be appreciated greatly

Comment: Probably no matching rows found. It works for me.

Comment: I checked if there were matching rows using the following: ``` SELECT count(*) FROM table1, table2 WHERE table2."ATT2" = table1."ATT2";``` This returns 14, explains why the above question query returns UPDATE 14. But still the table1 is not updated with the table2 prices.

Comment: Is there really a trailing space in the name of one of your columns?

Comment: A) How do you know it successfully updates? B) Is there supposed to be a space at end of `"Price "`? C) Did you do this in a transaction and forget to `COMMIT`? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: @jjanes yes there is a training space, this shouldn't change lead to my solution failing though.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver A) I to a SELECT * table1; to check that the specific prices in table1 have been updated with the prices in table2, which fails, after execution of the UPDATE above table1 is left unchanged, despite matches being found. B) answered C) it is not a transaction

Comment: @danielstafford Well, neither should anything else lead to it failing.

Comment: @jjanes Ok thanks for the help but the trailing space is needed, that is the name of one of my columns.

Comment: Do you have any BEFORE UPDATE triggers on table1?

Comment: The best explanation is that a transaction was opened and not committed. So what client are you running the query in? Are you doing the `UPDATE` and `SELECT` in the same client and/or session? Please add your answers to the question itself so folks don't have to search through all the comments for relevant information.

Comment: An alternate explanation is that the prices in `table1` and `table2` are the same for "ATT2". What do you see for `SELECT table1."Price " AS p1, table2."Price" AS p2 FROM table1, table2 WHERE table2."ATT2" = table1."ATT2";`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have updated the question now, hope that helps. I tried your example but sill no change. Thanks

Comment: Look at this in `pgAdmin` docs [Query tool](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.0/query_tool_toolbar.html#view-edit-data-resultset-control). Do you have `Autocommit` on and if not did you click the `Commit` button? In general you will have less hassle using the `psql` client.

Comment: Any chance you're looking at the wrong column? There might be a column `"Price "` (with space) **and** a column `"Price"` (without space) in the table and you're looking at the one without space?

Comment: You have not answered some  of the questions from comments above: 1) `Autocommit` status in `pgAdmin`? 2) Are the prices actually the same in `table1` and `table2`, per query `SELECT table1."Price " AS p1, table2."Price" AS p2 FROM table1, table2 WHERE table2."ATT2" = table1."ATT2";`?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a typo in your query:

```
UPDATE table1
SET "Price " = table2."Price" -- price has one extra space at the end
FROM table2
WHERE table2."ATT2" = table1."ATT2"
```

Comment: The extra space is needed, this is not the cause of the issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like that:

```
UPDATE table1
SET "Price " = (
   select table2."Price" 
   FROM table2
   WHERE table2."ATT2" = table1."ATT2")
```

I made some tests with this tables/update:

```
create table scientist1 (id integer, firstname varchar(100), lastname varchar(100));
        insert into scientist1 (id, firstname, lastname) values (1, 'albert 1', 'einstein');
        insert into scientist1 (id, firstname, lastname) values (2, 'isaac 1', 'newton');
        insert into scientist1 (id, firstname, lastname) values (3, 'marie 1', 'curie');

create table scientist2 (id integer, firstname varchar(100), lastname varchar(100));
        insert into scientist2 (id, firstname, lastname) values (1, 'albert 2', 'einstein');
        insert into scientist2 (id, firstname, lastname) values (2, 'isaac 2', 'newton');
        insert into scientist2 (id, firstname, lastname) values (3, 'marie 2', 'curie');

        
        
UPDATE scientist1
SET firstname = (select scientist2.firstname FROM scientist2
                 WHERE scientist2.id = scientist1.id);
```