# Uploading an excel file to a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, excel, pandas, postgresql

I have the following code that successfully uploads an excel file to postgreSQL

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

df = pd.read_excel(dir_path + '/'+file_name, "Sheet1")
engine= create_engine('postgresql://postgres:!Password@localhost/Database')
df.to_sql('identifier', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

However this leads to problems when trying to do simple queries such as updates in PgAdmin4.

Are there any other ways to insert an excel file into a postgeSQL table using python?

Comment: Do you get errors while loading data from Pandas to Postgres?

Comment: No errors but leads to problems such as not being able to UPDATE etc. Ideally I'd like to find a different way to upload the excel file to PostgreSQL.

Comment: What are the actual errors you are getting? Without seeing them it will be difficult to propose another solution as they may have nothing to do with the import process. Add the error messages as update to your question.

Comment: The issues i mentioned regarding UPDATE is shown in this question which is still not resolved. I used toy examples of tables and the UPDATE worked, so i concluded the reason the query doesn't work on my real example is my python pushing the excel to the postgreSQL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69865014/updating-a-table-in-postgresql-query

Comment: It was not resolved because you have not provided the information asked for in the comments. FYI, pretty sure the import and the `UPDATE` query issues are not directly related.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I've updated and answered all questions i believe. I'm unsure how to proceed since the UPDATE logic works when testing with simple tables but not with the tables created via the above python script.

Comment: No you haven't answered all the questions in the other SO question. See my new comment there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a faster way.

[Take a look.](https://towardsdatascience.com/upload-your-pandas-dataframe-to-your-database-10x-faster-eb6dc6609ddf)